# How to add dot separated routes in angular?

Tags: angular

How to add dot separated routes in angular?

Following is and example of a dot separated route in angular:

```
admin.mydomain.com
console.mydomain.com
```

How can I create above routes in angular?

Currently as I can see angular supports `/` separate routes.

is there a way to achieve the above??

I tried search online, but don't see a right blog post.

Comment: This is not a route. It is a subdomain that you can bifurcate in your server settings from which you can decide where you want to redirect your user based on the host.

Comment: So How can I achieve that? Do I need to create a separate app for the subdomains??

Comment: What if I'm using firebase then how can I achieve something like (sub domains as mentioned above)

Comment: You cannot. Angular routes are path based, not host based. If you are using eg Apache you could serve the same application under multiple virtual hosts.Then, based on the subdomain, apache could redirect you with eg `query param` that will init your application into `console` or `admin` state and remove query param from the browser. I don't think that this is worth it.

Comment: Alternative is to create separate applications that will share most of the code together.